# How to create a feature class in memory?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, feature-class, memory

I am trying to create a feature class in memory but I am not sure how to use the syntax.

My code looks like this:

```py
FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("", "in_memory/FC", "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED",
                                         "DISABLED", Coordinate_System, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Basically I seem to have problem defining the "out_path".

Answer (score 7):

I realized what was wrong. See the correct code here:

```
FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "FC", "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", Coordinate_System, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: Accept your answer with the checkbox!

Comment: Arash.   That's great you got it to work!  I am trying to figure out the in_memory workflow as well.  I am confused in this response and logan's link to the arcpy documentation on the arguments in ```arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management()```.  Where do I pass my file path?  It seems ```"FC"``` is the desired feature layer name, but where am I passing for instance ```fp = 'path/to/feature_class'```?

Comment: The first parameter is the output location. If you're not using a memory workspace, your path would replace "in_memory" in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the document [working with in memory workspace](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) in arcmap office site. the code below should work, tested in arcmap 10.3:

```
memory_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "feat", "Polygon")
memory_fc_path = memory_fc[0] # this is the path of the featureclass created .
```